# SIgnatures not matching after crashing Android Studio

Tags: android, crash, signature

Today my Android Studio crashed and corrupted a file. After I fixed that file it now says when I try to export and upload to Google Play that the signatures do not match. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Maybe use different Keystore?

Comment: Already tried that. No luck